# VirtualBox installation asked me a password with UEFI system

Tags: virtualbox, uefi, ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2 LTS inside 2 desktop computers and 1 laptop computer.

The laptop is an UEFI Ubuntu Studio system.

I installed Oracle VirtualBox 6.1 in all my machines, but... In the laptop, when I was installing VirtualBox, the installation asked me a password to start the UEFI system. Now, Each time I start that laptop, I get a little window with 3 options. Of course, if I click on the first option, "Continue normal", I get all my Ubuntu Studio installation without problems. But...

Is it normal, "by default"? ???

Comment: It has to do with Secure Boot. You can disable it in UEFI.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChanganAuto